# Which STL C++ container to use for a fixed size list?

Tags: c++, stl

I am having a consuming application which needs to store a maximum of 100 objects in a list to feed to a callback for processing, since it will be redundant to keep old data if the consumer does not catch up. As new data is arrived, it can simply overwrite the oldest element.

I was thinking of using circular buffer container and guessed that it would be deque , but found that it does not use circular list, as well as does not have option to set fixed maximum size.

There is a max_size method in dequeue, but documentation says "This is the maximum potential size the container can reach due to system or library implementation limitations."

Is there some other container I can use?

PS : I am using Visual C++ 2010 express

Answer (score 16):

There is no standard library container that does what you want directly. However, you should take a look at [Boost's Circular Buffer Container](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/circular_buffer/index.html). If you can't use Boost, you can at least view its source and redo it.

Comment: @Gman, no offense intended. I just think it's inappropriate to refer to Boost when there are fairly simple STL-based solutions. For various reasons, Boost is not an option for some people.

Comment: @Thomas: There are arguably simple stdlib-based solutions, and they can be implemented by looking at the Boost source-code...like I suggested. If you'd like, I can play the pedant card too.

Comment: @Thomas For any case where "Boost is not an option" the solution is not religiously sticking to nothing but STL, but rather preparing your arguments, sharpening your tongue and talking to the right people.

Comment: @Thomas: That's okay, if you want to down-vote then do so, that's for you to decide. :) (If you really changed your position, then let me know, but don't feel pressured.)

Comment: @Wilhelm, I don't know what you're trying to suggest by this comment. Does this mean that all situations developers should be able to use Boost if they have a sharp tougue, well prepared arguments and talk to the right people? If that's the case, I beg to differ. If you are developing under contract that says "standard libraries only," do you ask two sets of lawyers to get involved over the issue? If you are in school and the prof says "use STL," do you argue you should turn in your assignment using Boost?

Comment: @GMan, I reread the reasons for down voting on meta and my reason does not seem to be valid, according to some of the posts there.

Answer (score 16):

There's [boost::circular_buffer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/circular_buffer/doc/circular_buffer.html). Then there's

```
std::vector<T> vec(size);
vec[i % size] = newelem;
```

Answer (score 5):

Why not just use a vector with an index that increments mod 100 every time a new object is added?

```
    #define NUM_ELTS 100
    template < typename T >
    class CircularVector
    { 
    public:
       CircularVector() : idx(0)
       {
          vec = vector<T>(NUM_ELTS);
       }
       void push_back(T& elt)
       {
          vec[ idx++ % NUM_ELTS ] = elt;
       }
    private:
       int idx;
       vector<T> vec;
    };
```

Something like this, anyway.

Answer (score -4):

I typically roll my own circular buffers with linked lists (I guess it would be the "list" stl container).  This works well unless you need lots of random access to elements.  You could write a class containing a linked list and maintain the size yourself (add element at back, if size > threshold {remove element at front}, etc).  You can also make circular buffers with normal arrays/vectors by maintaining and wrapping head and tail indices, but you might be better off with the boost one mentioned by GMan.

Comment: Why use a linked list over a contiguous array? Downsides to linked lists for this are allocator load, memory overhead and fragmentation (cache misses). Upside is it's probably slightly easier to author.